# Action after save with Ajax Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have 2 models, **suppliers** and **bills**.

In my bills/_form.html.erb i'm creating a supplier via Ajax, because i don't 
wanna loose what user have typed in form fields and give him the possibility
to select the created supplier and create the bill.

bills/_form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'suppliers/form', modal: true %>
```

Everything is ok until here, the supplier is being created and saved after click submit.

```
Started POST "/suppliers" for ::1 at 2015-10-02 02:14:52 -0300
Processing by SuppliersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "supplier"=>{"cnpj"=>"1283981293", "fancy_name"=>"Supplier Test 3", "corporate_name"=>"Supplier Test 3", "state_registration"=>"19827391823", "main_supplier"=>"0", "alternative_supplier"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Salvar"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `suppliers` (`fancy_name`, `corporate_name`, `cnpj`, `state_registration`, `main_supplier`, `alternative_supplier`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Supplier Test 3', 'Supplier Test 3', '1283981293', '19827391823', 0, 0, '2015-10-02 05:14:52.363531', '2015-10-02 05:14:52.363531')
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```

I have already tried the respond_to in suppliers_controller:

```
format.js   { render 'bills/supplier', status: :created, location: @supplier }
```

and created the supplier.js.erb in bills views folder:

bills/supplier.js.erb

```
$('#supplier_name').append("<%= j render (@supplier) %>");
$('#modal_add_supplier').modal_success();
```

But now i get this:

```
Started POST "/suppliers" for ::1 at 2015-10-02 02:16:45 -0300
Processing by SuppliersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "supplier"=>{"cnpj"=>"1283981293", "fancy_name"=>"Supplier Test 3", "corporate_name"=>"Supplier Test 3", "state_registration"=>"19827391823", "main_supplier"=>"0", "alternative_supplier"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Salvar"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (6.2ms)  INSERT INTO `suppliers` (`fancy_name`, `corporate_name`, `cnpj`, `state_registration`, `main_supplier`, `alternative_supplier`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Supplier Test 3', 'Supplier Test 3', '1283981293', '19827391823', 0, 0, '2015-10-02 05:16:45.868491', '2015-10-02 05:16:45.868491')
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered bills/supplier.js.erb (7.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial suppliers/_supplier with {:locale=>[:"pt-BR"], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/anchietajr/Documents/SISTEMA_UNIX/unix/app/views"
  * "/Users/anchietajr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
  * "/Users/anchietajr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
```

I wanna know how can i show validation erros in my form and
how can i call an action after submit this form and manipulate DOM elements in
my bills/_form.html.erb to show the created supplier, knowing that i'm using a remote form that is in suppliers/_form.html.erb.

[Here is the gist.](https://gist.github.com/anchietajunior/328948b79b51ecd687d5)

Answer (score 3):

Rails is looking for a partial. Partial names start with a underscore:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial suppliers/_supplier
```

Just change the file name from `bills/supplier.js.erb` to `bills/_supplier.js.erb`

Comment: I've changed the file name, it's still working, the supplier was created, but now i get this: 

`Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 58ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template bills/supplier with {:locale=>[:"pt-BR"], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. `